# Processing the columns of a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to understand how to set a column of a two dimensional array to 0.

I follow this code snippet from C programming textbook by K.N. King.

```
   int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], (*p)[NUM_COLS], i;
   ...
   for (p = &a[0]; p < &a[NUM_ROWS]; p++)
      (*p)[i] = 0;
```

I genuinely don't understand how this works. Greatly appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all related to how an array is converted to a pointer on access, see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3).

In your case you have a two dimensional array of `int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];`. Which in reality is an array of arrays of `int[NUM_COLS]`. (an array of 1D arrays).

When you access `a`, `a` is converted to a pointer to the first 1D array and is of type `int (*)[NUM_COLS]` (a pointer to an array of `NUM_COLS` integers).

You declare `p` as a pointer to an array of `NUM_COLS` integers, so `p` is type compatible with `a`. You can simply initialize:

```
p = a;
```

(instead of `p = &a[0];`)

In your `for` loop you loop from `p = a;` (a pointer to the first 1D array), and loop while `p` is less than `&a[NUM_ROWS]` (the address 1-after the final 1D array) incrementing `p` each iteration (and since `p` is a pointer to `int[NUM_COLS]`, `p` points to the next row each time you increment `p`)

When you dereference `p` you have an array of `int[NUM_COLS]`, so when you address `(*p)[i] = 0;` you are setting the i<sup>th</sup> element of that row to `0`.

That's it in a nutshell. Let me know if you are still confused and where and I'm happy to try and explain further.

Comment: What does `&a[NUM_ROWS]`  mean? Does it same as `a[NUM_ROWS]`(pointer to int 1d array)?

Comment: `&a[NUM_ROWS]` is the address of `a[NUM_ROWS]`. Which the only valid indexes for the rows in `a` are `0 -> NUM_ROWS-1`, so `a[NUM_ROWS]` is one past the end of `a` which is a valid *address* for the array, but not one that holds a value. In effect it can be used to mark the end of the array only. The `[..]` operates as a dereference. so `a[NUM_ROWS]` would be a 1D array which on access is converted to a pointer to the first element in the `NUM_ROWS` row (which as discussed is the first address after `a`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your clarification makes perfect sense to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. This is one area that catches all new C/C++ programmers. So might as well go ahead and learn it -- it will save you untold hours of head-scratching later... `:)` YES, `&a[NUM_ROWS]` is simply `a + NUM_ROWS`. (recall `a[NUM_ROWS] == *(a + NUM_ROWS)` so `&*(a + NUM_ROWS) == a + NUM_ROWS`.)

Comment: Yes, you got it. `a` on access is a pointer to an array of `NUM_COLS` integers. You have `NUM_ROWS` of those. With pointer arithmetic set by `type` (**type is king**), `p` being a pointer to an array of `NUM_COLS` integers means `p++` advances `p` to point to the next array of `NUM_COLS` integers (the next row in `a`).